# Best material to make a solar sail

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, materials

So, in this project o’ mine, a newly-formed world state is trying to whip humanity into shape and is making some major changes to society in order to protect the environment. First thing’s first, no more chemical rockets. People are now using clean, electromagnetic launch systems to get into orbit and then light sails for interplanetary transits. The solar sails of most spacecraft are shaped like large fish-fins on either side, and are given a quick laser-boost to speed up the journey from Earth to Mars, to about 8 hours.

What would be the best material to make these light sails from? I am guessing either aluminium foil or some kind of nanomaterial for reflectivity, but I am unsure. Plz help!

Comment: Define best. Cost-wise? Texture-wise? Political ROI-wise? Anything else-wise?

Comment: Is it more important to you that the trip from earth to Mars take eight hours,  or that the type of propulsion be a laser sail? It requires more than 6 gees of constant acceleration to even reach the speed you'd need to cross 54 million km in 8 hours, much less get there in 8 hours.

Comment: Make it from Lasagne.

Answer (score 9):

> given a quick laser-boost to speed up the journey from Earth to Mars, to about 8 hours.

So, there's a problem here. The shortest distance from Earth to Mars is ~78 million kilometres, and on average it is ~225 million kilometres. A constant acceleration transit (where you boost until the half way point, and then brake continuously til you get there) across 80 million km taking 8 hours requires a thrust of near 40 gravities. You can be assured that no humans will be travelling in such a spacecraft, because they'll be dead shortly after acceleration starts. It only gets worse for longer distances.

So, initial problems:

- You're too impatient. A hundred years ago, people were used to travel to distance places taking days or weeks.
- You haven't thought about speeds and accelerations at all.

Now, lets say you're doing a continuous 1 gee brachistochrone instead. This would take about 2 days to cross the shortest distance, and 3.5 days in the average case. Lets imagine you have a *very* small and spartan spacecraft... something like the [Apollo CSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_command_and_service_module), with a mass of about 10 tonnes.

Lightsails accelerate because photons have momentum. From *The Starflight Handbook*, if a beam of light with power $E_b$ is perfectly reflected by a sail-equipped spacecraft of total mass $M_s$, then that sail will experience a change in velocity $\dot{V_s} = {2E_b \over M_s c}$. You can re-arrange this to work out the required beam power for a massless sail easily enough, and get **~14.7 terawatts**. That's a lot of oomph, and lasers are notoriously inefficient so you'll need to put a *lot* more power in to get that much power out. Remember this is for a spacecraft with a total mass of 10 tonnes and a perfectly reflective sail which you'll be hard pressed to create in real life! I'll briefly revisit the size of the necessary lasers (large) and power supplies (*really* large) below.

As for what materials you might use... well. I looked at [real world lightsail materials](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40170/29766) in an answer on space.SE, and they're much to poor to even slightly approach your requirements. If a sail of the size I just suggested was subject to an irradiance of only 1MW/m<sup>2</sup> it would need an area of ~14.7 square kilometres. If it were circular, it would have a radius of over 2.1km. And that's for a tiny 10 tonne spacecraft, with a massless sail!

And not only must the sail be massless, it must also be strong enough to withstand the light pressure inducing that 1G acceleration, so you'll need it to have considerable tensile strength and you'll need a lot of massless rigging and spars to support it. The more realistic you make the sail, the heavier it becomes, and the larger it must be and the slower it can accelerate and the longer the journey times.

Jordin Kare's [Sailbeam](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/library/meetings/fellows/oct01/597Kare.pdf) idea required near-magical [dielectric sails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror) using [CVD diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_vapor_deposition) to give them their incredible performance. These materials may or may not be practical to ever make, but do give an upper plausible limit for lightsail performance and... good news! They might actually work for your needs, *and* be high enough performance that they don't need to be kilometres across. They do still need to be hundreds of metres across because your laser still needs to be able to hit it and deliver all its energy across distances of tens of millions of kilometres. Because of [diffraction limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system), your drive laser needs to be very large indeed... the final mirror of a perfect 500nm wavelength laser needs to be >250m across to hit a lightsail 100m across at 40 million km, and that's the best case scenario.

Remember that a multi-terawatt laser that can focus onto a spacecraft half way to Mars is more or less indistinguishable from an interplanetary weapon! You need two lasers per space craft (one to boost, one to brake), and one of each pair needs to be operating for the entire flight, and that 15TW is for a *single* tiny little spacecraft! Every inhabited body in your system needs to be *bristling* with laser death cannon in order for this process to work for you.

Each one needs to be driven by a pretty large nuclear (presumably fusion) reactor, because solar power just isn't up to the job. Even at Earth orbit, solar irradiance is ~1361 W/m<sup>2</sup>. Your 14.7TW laser, if it were perfectly efficient (which it won't be, not by a large margin) would need more than **10000km<sup>2</sup> of solar panels** to drive it. By the time you get out as far as Mars, solar irradiance is a mere 586W/m<sup>2</sup> and it gets much worse further out thanks to inverse square scaling. So nuclear is the only way, and you'll need a big nuclear fuel mining and refining and transporting business!

So what can be done?

- Don't use lightsails for fast transit. Even laser driven ones.
- Consider using something like Kare's sailbeam as a way to provide high-thrust propulsion across long distances without the need for huge lasers that can shoot tens of millions of kilometres.
- Other boost and brake systems might also help, such as Winglee's [MagBeam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagBeam), being a more efficient way to push things than bouncing light off them. [Magnetic sails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_sail) in general might be better than lightsails for short haul flights.
- Don't be so impatient. Taking a week to fly to Mars isn't that much of an imposition, and makes every other aspect of your spaceflight technology and infrastructure much, much simpler.

Comment: For reference, 10,000 square kilometers is almost exactly the size of [Basilicata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilicata), an "administrative region" in Italy. In American terms, it's between the size of a county and a state. Or, imagine if [Cyprus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus) were entirely covered in lasers.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what starfish prime said, you might want to conceder just using reaction engines and a sail combination, for example, using that perfectly reflective sail as a parabola, focusing the light to a tiny collector panel at the tip of your spacecraft.

Use that energy to drive massive hall-effect engines, heat up your reaction mass and spew hydrogen out the back of your craft, or some other, more conventional engine system, beaming the required power to it using your laser.

If your still determined to use light-sails, then, depending on the technology level of the society you are describing, you might want to look into a system of collectors and mirrors directly around the sun, think the orbit of mercury, and use all that free energy to power your massive solar-pumped lasers.

As Starfish already said, the acceleration and required energy for a brachistochrone of 1G from earth to mars is truly epic, but one way to minimize the required energy would be be to exploit orbital momentum exchange tethers, which Kurzgesagt made a truly spectacular video on.

This 'skyhook' acts like a giant 300 kilometer sling, slowing its tip relative to the surface so a shuttlecraft can catch it, then catapult it to the top of its orbit and throwing it at double orbital speed towards the target. A tether on the mars side would do the same but in reverse, slowing the ship back down, reclaiming the energy from the earth-hook in the process and speeding up a little. When a shuttle leaves for earth, it carries the initial energy from the earth-hook back from the mars-hook. In effect it's like throwing kinetic energy back and forth, never truly loosing it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqwpQarrDwk

This could make transit even faster, as you start moving at a very good speed, FOR FREE. It works fantastic when you can launch hypersonic shuttlecraft with magnetic rail-guns at orbital speed.